# User selectable CSV columns to import to Datagridview C#

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagridview

I am presently importing 2 different CSVs into 2 different Datagridviews.

I have googled and googled and I am trying to find out if there is a way to do the following:

1. Import the full CSV without headers into a temp datagridview?
2. The user can then select the columns to import into the permanent datagridview.

I want to make it as simple as possible in the temp datagridview where the user can use the temp datagridview headers as dropdowns and select between for example X, Y, Time, Sequence.

Once the user has selected what he wants, the temp datagridview will be imported to the permanent datagridview with the selected headers, rows and columns.

I have no code for this and have no idea where to start.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction or give me samples code to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by using the headers as stopdown to select between for example X, Y, Time, Sequence? Should the user select in advance (before seeing the data) the columns that should be displayed?

Comment: I want to make the headers in the temp datagridview, comboboxes populated with X,Y, Time, Sequence. For example there are 10 columns in the CSV and all 10 columns and the info in the rows shows in the temp datagridview. The user selects in the temp datagridview, column 2 as X, column 5 as Y and presses the import button. The 2 selected columns imports to the permanent datagridview.